# Does "MERIT OMNIA VINCIT" mean "Merit conquers all"?

Tags: translation-check

Trying to create a phrase based off of Labor omnia vincit. I figure I can just swap in "Merit."

Also does "Merit ex vi" mean "strength from merit" ?

TIA !

Comment: Merit comes from a Latin word, but it's not itself a Latin word.

Answer (score 3):

Almost! You can't just substitute an English word for a Latin word, but fortunately in your case *merit* comes from the Latin word *meritum* (itself coming from the Latin word *merere* meaning 'I earn'). A *meritum* is "something earned", though it can be both positive and negative.

You'll often see the word in the plural meaning "the things you earned", which would make it closer to the more abstract meaning "merit" has in your example sentence. In that case, you just want *merita omnia vincunt.*

Do be aware though that words change forms (like English does - do, did, doing, done) depending on how it's used.

> Also does "Merit ex vi" mean "strength from merit" ?

*Meritum ex vi* means "something earned from strength" (but in the sense of physical strength, or even force/violence), but "strength from merit" could be e.g. *vis ex meritis*.

Comment: To me, meritum, especially in the singular, would seem to refer to a (single) meritorious act. At the very least, I think you'd want to use the plural merita (and vincunt, of course). Alternatively, virtus is used by, e.g., Sallust, to express the idea of 'merit' in the sense of excellence of character, which is presumably what the original poster is going for. Nevertheless, its obvious links to the English word 'virtue' may be a disadvantage here.

Comment: @cnread I thought I saw *meritum* being used more abstractly before in the singular, but *merita* is better, you're right. I'll look later to see if I can find what I had in mind. Re: *virtus*, it's a great suggestion, too, you should post it as your own!

Comment: *Vires ex meritis* could also be an option, to get away from the often negative connotations of singular *vis*.